# Simulate browser - Authentication and performing actions

Tags: php, curl, websocket, autologin

What I'm trying to accomplish here is a way to log in to a given page and perform certain actions that only logged in users can do.

I've tried cURL (with PHP), but the login form has some security fields (hidden inputs) with random text to verify if the user is real and is using a real browser. I need an effective way to get pass that.

If possible, the script would load the page, fill in the necessary field, submit the form and save the session and cookie login to perform future actions.

Any ideas?

I'm not very familiar with 'websockets', but would it work?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
https://www.pingdom.com/transactionmonitor/

That site does exactly what I need, what technology are they using? Websockets to interact with a website?

Comment: Simply not something you can do with PHP.

Comment: "to verify if the user is real and is using a real browser" -- they did that for some reason. It's not a good thing - to cheat.

Comment: I'm just trying to automate some really boring tasks I do everyday. Nothing that can possible hurt someone.

Comment: This can definitely be done with cURL. You could even set up a cron job to make it do it automatically

Comment: create cookie jar , scrape the cookies and store it in cookie jar, this way you will get values of hidden fields and now reiterate the action with login id and pass thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cURL, you could scrape the content of the hidden fields, store in a session and use once you need to send the data. Other wise, it isn't exactly possible with PHP.